# Где найти сайт angular.io переведенный на русский язык?

Tags: angular2, angular4

Интересует подробная документация по Angular 4 (именно v2+ а не AngularJS) на русском языке. Не очередные авторские уроки, а вот прям как на angular.io, но на великом и могучем. Буду очень признателен, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вот [тут](https://metanit.com/web/angular2/) была попытка перевода...

Comment: скорее всего пока нигде

Comment: @Grundy А последний ответ, что-то что можно оставить или фтопку?

Comment: @0xdb вообще похоже, но не знаю как качество перевода

Answer (score 1):

Нашел книгу перевкеденную на русский язык [здесь](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/142143733/)

Потрясающе подробно и ясно все разъяснено до мельчайших деталей

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть перевод от русского сообщества https://angular24.ru